# Major lag on Minecraft Servers ( I have good fps)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, performance

Lately I am getting very bad lag on every server (e.g  Skyrealms Hypixel Mineplex and every other multiplayer server that I like to play). I have tried reinstalling Minecraft, logging out and logging in, Optifine, watched Youtube and changed my Minecraft Settings.

Whenever I join a server it says I have 200-100 fps and low ping but the chat does load, can't break any blocks. My internet should be okay because my phone works with the same internet with my PC (Windows 10). I am having a bad time playing with lag, it happened suddenly.

Please tell me ideas how to reduce lag or not get any lag.

Comment: Where are you from and where is the server hosted?

Comment: I am from Australia and I think it's Mostly America

Comment: Well, that's the reason. Refer to mabu's answer for an explanation on what lag is. But pretty much you lag because the connection isn't very good (and it may not even be on your end!)

Comment: @Oak Thank you for mentioning my answer. I've added some details to explain what the problem is exactly.

Answer (score 5):

The distance between you and the server locations are causing the lags. If you press <kbd>TAB</kbd> in Minecraft you can see the ping (latency) right next to your name. Five green bars would be great, the less you have the more lags appear. The ping is extremely important for lag-free playing. As you said, if the ping is too high you even won't be able to place or remove blocks. That's because you run into timeout on serverside with your requests to place/remove blocks. The lower the ping the better.

Example for a good connection, low ping. You should have few or even no lags:

[image: good connection, low ping]

Example for a bad connection, high ping. It's more likely that some lags appear if your connection status looks like this:

[image: bad connection, high ping]

Please refer to [this Minecraft forum post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/archive/forum-1-8-update-discussion/935537-ping-meter) to see an example of the ping meter. Further I found [this helpful website](http://minecraft-mp.com/server-ping/) which shows Minecraft servers with the best ping at your location.

**Edit:**

Having lots of FPS doesn't help you out in this situation. The frames per second is the amount of single frames (images) your graphics card can produce and send to your monitor in one second. Ping instead measures the round-trip time for messages sent from the originating host (you) to a destination computer (your minecraft server in the US) that are echoed back to the source (you again). If that takes too long you are getting asynchronous with the servers and the other players and you get lags. See [this Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(video_games)) for more information about ping.

You could look for servers which are closer to you and which have lower pings.